# Visual Studio 2013 create SQL trigger error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a trigger on a SQL table in Visual Studio 2013 but I'm getting an error

> SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'End Of File' Expecting '.'

This is the SQL code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeMethod1 
ON UserTable 
AFTER INSERT AS 
    EXTERNAL NAME "Main.Site.Header1.OnEvent"
```

It is the first time I'm trying SQL trigger so maybe I missed something..

Anyone have an idea of what's the problem ?

Comment: This blog might help http://geekswithblogs.net/tonyt/archive/2010/03/05/138363.aspx. A comment at the bottom could be useful "you can rid yourself of this issue by changing the build action, on the script files properties, to "None". "

Comment: I don't have a "file", i just want to "Update" an existing Table. I did "Add->New Trigger" and I wrote the code from my question

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: I created a **SQL Server database** in a asp.net application.
The database is a .mdf file. After that I right clicked on my table and added a new trigger

Comment: Try without the quotes around the procedure name. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, double quotes act the same as square brackets and delimit names of objects. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM "Customers"
```

It's not necessary here but if the name of an object is complex you need to delimit it with either double quotes or square brackets

```
SELECT * FROM [Order Details]
SELECT * FROM "Order Details"
```

If an object is referred to with multiple parts like a schema or database, you would have to delimit each individual part, not quote the whole name as in:
SELECT * FROM "dbo"."Customers"
not

```
SELECT * FROM "dbo.Customers"
```

In the code you showed, you have the whole four part name quoted:

```
"Main.Site.Header1.OnEvent"
```

EXTERNAL NAME requires three parts, the first is the assembly, the second is the class and the third is the method. If you have a class with a namespace then it has a two part name. I am guessing from context what you really want here is:

```
Main."Site.Header1".OnEvent"
```

because Site is the namespace and Header1 is the class, so the second parameter would need to be delimited to indicate the complex name, the same way "Order Details" would need to be delimited because it contains a space.